# Should 'battery-manager' be merged into 'power-management'?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request, tag-cleanup

I just encountered the [battery-manager](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/battery-manager) (x4) tag and wondered where I've seen something "synonym". Obviously this was [power-management](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/power-management) (x14). Taking a look at the questions tagged by the latter, the terms "saving battery", "draining battery" suggest a strong relation.

Do we really need those tags separately? Does a separation make any sense here, after all? I'd suggest merging `battery-manager` into `power-management` and make the former a synonym to the latter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I approved the synonym that you requested; I don't see a meaningful reason to keep them separate, especially since the traffic for both is relatively low.